# How do I deal with server response when overriding the sync function in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've been trying to connect my backbone.js application to an existing Codeigniter API. I looked at the todos example on github and built up from there. 
I'm overriding the findAll function, which is invoked on 'read' and am trying to get the pages and return them back to the fetch function:

findAll: function() {
    console.log('synch - findAll');

```
var url = "/folio/get/8";
var data = ''; 

var postmethod = 'GET';

$.ajax({
    url : url,
    type : postmethod,
    async: false,
    data: data,
    success: function(response) 
    {
                    console.debug("response",response);
        console.debug("response.pages", response["pages"]);
        return _.values(response["pages"]);
    }
});
```

}

The API returns something like this - output via the console.debug("response", response):

```
{
    "id": "8",
    "facebook_id": "123456789",
    "title": "title",
    "access_date": null,
    "rating_avg": "0",
    "pages": [
        {
            "id": "6",
            "picture1": {
                "id": "3",
                "tag": "1",
                "tip": "Crazy",
                "facebook_picture_id": "1239102391023"
            },
            "picture2": "28",
            "picture3": "29",
            "picture4": null,
            "picture5": null,
            "picture6": null,
            "caption1": "caption 1",
            "caption2": "caption 2",
            "sequence": "2",
            "folio": "8",
            "ts": "2012-04-10 15:13:23",
            "template": "#page-template-2"
        },
        {
            "id": "5",
            "picture1": "24",
            "picture2": "25",
            "picture3": "26",
            "picture4": null,
            "picture5": null,
            "picture6": null,
            "caption1": "caption 1",
            "caption2": "caption 2",
            "sequence": "4",
            "folio": "8",
            "ts": "2012-04-10 15:13:23",
            "template": "#page-template-2"
        }
    ]
}
```

but then console.debug("response.pages", response["pages"]) prints out "undefined". Why does it do that?

Thanks a lot in advance!

-------------------- edit ---------------------

Thanks for your answer. The tip that I can just do ajax calls from within the model is really helpful. The thing is that I am trying to get several pages into one PageList Collection:

```
$(function(){
  // Page Collection
  // ---------------

  var PageList = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: Page,
    localStorage: new Store("wickes-backbone"), // this to get hold of my overwritten localstorage file - it is not actually a localStorage

    nextOrder: function() {
      if (!this.length) return 1;
      return this.last().get('order') + 1;
    },

    comparator: function(page) {
      return page.get('order');
    }

  });

  window.Pages = new PageList;
});
```

so within the appview intitialize function I am calling

```
Pages.fetch();
```

which populates all the pages and updates the view. I'm not really sure how to do that within the model itself?

Comment: can you post your view/model?

Comment: when changing the code to:
console.debug("response.pages", response.pages);

the console prints:
response.pages undefined

so no different result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is how you're using the success function in the $.ajax():

```
$.ajax({
    url : url,
    type : postmethod,
    async: false,
    data: data,
    success: function(response) 
    {
        console.debug("response",response);
        console.debug("response.pages", response["pages"]);
        return _.values(response["pages"]);
    }
});
```

If you return something from the success function on an AJAX call, it's going straight into the bitbucket. That _.values() isn't heading anywhere. What comes out of a $.ajax() call is a promise, that's all. That promise can have .done(), .fail() etc. attached to it later, it can also be used with .when() and for other purposes. However, it has nothing to do with the success function it will call later. That's equivalent to just a .done() function attached to that promise.

My guess is that what you really want is for AJAX to finish and then manipulate the results and then set them on the model.

In general though, trying to force Backbone to be synchronous is not how it's meant to be used. Even if you don't intend to use the Sync built into Backbone and skip the fetch, save, etc. it still happily accommodates being called like so (and note that the model will just update when it updates, just like you were doing a fetch):

```
var myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  goGetSomeData : function () {
    var scope = this;

    $.ajax(....).done(
      function (results) {
        scope.set(results);
      }
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, the advice that communication with the server can be made directly within the model is very helpful. However I need to update several models at the same time and am not sure how to do that without the sync function. I edited the question above. I would be really thankful if you could have another look.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this in your PageList Backbone Collection:

```
  parse: function(response) {
    return response.pages
  }
```

This does two things:

1. Uses `.pages` to reference the `pages` array in your response. From what I can tell from your code, backbone is using the overall object response to determine the objects in your collection.
2. Tells backbone to uses the `pages` array to instantiate the models in your collection. It does this by overriding the native `parse` method and returning what you really want (the pages array)

Doing this *should* get your page objects into one PageList collection. This has worked for me in a similar situation. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I worked out what was actually going wrong here. As mentioned by John Munsch in the first answer, the ajax request wasn't quite right. This was actually not an issue with backbone, but with the ajax call I was making. First of all I changed it to be json and secondly I created a variable 'pages' outside of the ajax call which can remember the response and return it to the synch function:

```
findAll: function() {

    var url = "/folio/get/8";
    var pages;
    var postmethod = 'GET';

    $.ajax({
         type: postmethod,
         url: url,
         async: false,
         beforeSend: function(x) {
          if(x && x.overrideMimeType) {
           x.overrideMimeType("application/j-son;charset=UTF-8");
          }
     },
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(data){
         console.debug("data", data);
         console.debug("data.pages", data.pages);
         pages = data.pages;

     }
    });

    return pages;

},
```

Thanks very much to everyone for your help, I learned a lot from your answers!